# Non-base58 character error in create Fungible token in Solana

Tags: node.js, token, solana, solana-web3js, metaplex

I am trying to creat fungible token using metaplex([here](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/spl-tokens/how-to-create-a-fungible-spl-token-with-the-new-metaplex-token-standard/))

The rest is working fine but when sending transaction there was error.

I found that `createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction` in add transaction has different type of props in guide. If I use typescript for this, it throws `createMetadataAccountArgsV2 is not a type of PublicKey`.

So I checked `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` and it's props were `account: createMetadataAccountV2InstructionAccounts` and `programId?: PublicKey` which is different from [here](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/caeab0f7/token-metadata/js/src/generated/instructions/CreateMetadataAccountV2.ts#L73).

How can I pass parameters in `createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction`?

Or if it's not a problem, what is wrong with the project(I just copy and paste the guide)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Finally I create token.

I didn't use `createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction`.
Instead I use `createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction` for transaction and it works fine.

```
const createNewTokenTransaction = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: mintKeypair.publicKey,
      space: MINT_SIZE,
      lamports: requiredBalance,
      programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    }),
    createInitializeMintInstruction(
      mintKeypair.publicKey,
      MINT_CONFIG.numDecimals,
      mintAuthority,
      freezeAuthority,
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID),
    createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
      payer.publicKey,
      tokenATA,
      payer.publicKey,
      mintKeypair.publicKey,
    ),
    createMintToInstruction(
      mintKeypair.publicKey,
      tokenATA,
      mintAuthority,
      MINT_CONFIG.numberTokens * Math.pow(10, MINT_CONFIG.numDecimals),
    ),
    createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction(
      {
        metadata: metadataPDA,
        mint: mintKeypair.publicKey,
        mintAuthority: mintAuthority,
        payer: payer.publicKey,
        updateAuthority: mintAuthority,
      },
      {
        createMetadataAccountArgsV3:
        {
          data: ON_CHAIN_METADATA,
          isMutable: true,
          collectionDetails: null
        },
      }
    ),
  );
```

It's modified code.

Hope this will help you. :)